# How can an online store recognize me - MAC addres? Something else?

Tags: ip, privacy, web

I have problem with an online store and I wonder how they can recognize me - I was thinking about MAC address? Or something else I'm unaware of?

I help people in my community - especially older poeple, without knowledge of Internet or English - to purchase supplements in a big online store from US.

Usually I just create a new account for a person I'm buying supplements. I order using their address, and pay with my PayPal.

Recently, store began to block my accounts and reject orders.

I've contacted them - they told me you can't have multiple accounts, only 5 accounts per household. They weren't interested in a fact that every order is using completely different address and name.

They even blocked my IP, so I can't create any new account and can't log into any of the old accounts.

I installed CyberGhost, to change my IP.

After doing so, I was able to create an account. But after some time order was cancelled as usual and account was blocked.

I thought - oh, it's probably a PayPal account - they noticed it's still me.

I "borrowed" PayPal account from my friend - completely different name, address, city than mine.

I created new account, using CyberGhost to change my IP to different one, and paid with friend's PayPal (PayPal balance, so no debit card involved)

And my account was still blocked and order cancelled, as usual.

And I'm confused - how they knew that was me?

Comment: Same browser instance?

Comment: [Evercookie](https://samy.pl/evercookie/)?

Comment: Not an answer, but the flip side perspective. An online drugstore is heavily regulated. They're required to have very tight controls. Someone gaming their system can land them in serious trouble and affect their ability to conduct business. You have innocent intentions, but the way you want to handle orders is bad for their business. And they probably don't have a cost-effective way to create exception handling for one unusual customer. Best bet: find another online store. Contact them in advance and discuss your situation. Let them suggest how to handle orders within their constraints.

Comment: Any site which is subject to heavy demand and regulatory scrutiny is going to be incredibly careful about who and how they deal with people. Using a VPN service or tor or any anonimising service will raise a red flag that your account may be suspicious and require intervention.

Answer (score 5):

Browser and device fingerprinting let web sites identify if different requests are coming from the same browser or device.

Web sites can gather a lot of data from your device, for example:

- Browser (Chrome, Firefox, etc.) and version
- List of browser plugins and version
- Operating System (Windows, Linux, OSX, iOS, Android, etc.) and version
- Primary language
- Timezone
- Screen Resolution and depth
- System Fonts
- Use of Ad block
- Flash Availability
- WebGL Renderer (graphic card)

Using big data techniques this mix of features can create an unique identity of your device that helps them to identify you.

If you want to know how much information websites can get from your device click [here (amiunique)](https://amiunique.org/) or [here (panopticlick)](https://panopticlick.eff.org/).